# how to use intent on android wear(wear os by google)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wear-2.0

I tried to use intent like this on ticwatch pro.
However, the application stopped.
I want some information about this.

This code is in MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

This code is in TestActivity

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

This code is activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There are some problem solving instruction under [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). The stack trace will explain the problem.

Comment: Have you declared your TestActivity in the manifest file? Please post the stack trace from Logcat when the app crashes.

Comment: I forget to declare TestActivity in the manifest file
Thank you for that